# In PySpark, how do you fit a straight line to every row of the data and append gradient to the dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
uniqueKey | Month1 | Month2 | ... | MonthN
a         | 1      | 2      | ... | 3
b         | 3      | 4      | ... | 5
```

Where each row is unique. I want to fit a straight line to each row and append the gradient value to the end of the dataframe.

I know how to `SparkML` to fit an OLS to the whole dataframe but this dataframe is huge and I'd like to do it in a distributed fashion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Also please provide what you have tried with an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).